# Cant run Angular Cli App

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I hit ng new myApp I get an error :

`Cannot find module '/home/darko/node_modules/chai/package.json'`

Tried to install chai again but no success.

Comment: ls /home/darko/node_modules/chai?

Comment: no, it is the same as i wrote - with package.json